# Can the interval category be expressed as a colimit?

Tags: category-theory

A category with two objects and no non-identity morphisms can be expressed as the colimit of a diagram consisting of two copies of the trivial category. Naively, I would think that the interval category might be the colimit (or 2-colimit) of a diagram consisting of two copies of the trivial category connected by the identity functor (call this colimit $C$). However, the definition of colimit requires that everything commute. So, we have two morphisms $0, 1 : \text{pt} \to C$, and a commutative triangle $0 \cong 1 \circ \text{id}$, which tells me that $0 \cong 1$, even though, for the interval category, there should merely be a natural transformation from $0$ to $1$.

So, is it even possible to express the interval category as a (co)limit, or is it something that we just have to assume is there? Is there a weaker sort of limit that would work? Is there a different universal property I should be looking at?

Comment: I haven't proven this, but I'm pretty sure any diagram you make out of $0$ and $1$ will only have discrete categories as its colimit. You could express the interval category as a colimit, but only in terms of something more "complex" than the interval category. The interval category is a pretty fundamental part of **Cat**, so personally I would take it as something "axiomatic". Gray's book "Formal Category Theory: Adjointness for 2-Categories" contains statements like: "The properties of **Cat** which will be extended to representable 2-categories all depend ultimately on the category **2**."

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator*{\colim}{colim}$
You can obtain the category $[1]=\{0\to 1\}$ [joining](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/join+of+simplicial+sets) two copies of the terminal category $[0]=\{0\}$. A join is a colimit: given simplicial sets $X,Y$ you have to compute
$$
\colim_{[n]\to [p+ q+1]} X_p\times Y_q
$$ or, in a more elegant way, the [convolution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution)
$$
\int^{p,q} X_p\times Y_q \times \Delta(-,[p]\oplus [q])
$$ where $\oplus$ is the [ordinal sum](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ordinal+sum) $[p]\oplus [q]:=[p+q+1]$.

Comment: The reference to simplicial sets comes across as a non-sequitur without a mentioning how this gives you a category as a result. The ordinal sum (and thus the [join](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/join+of+simplicial+sets#definition)) is also [defined](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ordinal+sum#ordinal_sum_of_categories) in terms of the interval category, so this seems circular to me. In fact, it seems when spelled out it's almost the same as saying that $[1]$ is the (trivial) colimit of $[1]:\mathbf{1}\to\mathbf{Cat}$!

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is a lovely way to motivate homotopy colimits. The homotopy colimit of the diagram $\{1 = 1\}$, where "$=$" denotes the identity of a point (considered as a simplicial set, an $\infty$-groupoid, a topological space, or any equivalent model of homotopy theory). A homotopy colimit can be thought of as a bundle indexed by the (geometric realization of) the diagram shape.

A homotopy colimit is characterized by the property that any map out of it is equivalently characterized by a homotopy cocone out of the diagram; in this case, this means that a path in a space is characterized by a pair of points in it and a homotopy between them.

In general, the homotopy colimit of $A = A$ is the product space $A\times \text{hocolim} \{ 1 = 1\}$.